# Open and write to a new window but forcing it to be cross domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, window.open, cross-domain-policy

I need to open a new window and write some user supplied html with possible css and javascript.

I do not want them to have access to any of the cookies or give them access to anything else from the main webpage.

Currently with:

```
var text = userSuppliedText;
var newWindow = window.open("");
newWindow.newWindow.document.write(text);
newWindow.close();
```

This makes the new window's domain to be the same as the parent page. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: newWindow.document.write(text); from Scott Marcus

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to dynamically create a new window in a different domain than the page that creates it (and that's a good thing for security purposes).

Since your desire is to open the page in a different domain, your best bet is to create a page in another domain and set up an AJAX request that sends data to it, but of course, CORS will need to be configured for cross-domain access.

Also (FYI), `newWindow.write(text);` would fail. It would need to be: `newWindow.document.write(text);`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. 

I guess then I could get by with just escaping the javascript somehow.